# DropdownList has validation error when EnableClientValidation = false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a problem where my view is reporting a input-validation-error on a dropdownlist.

I get this error in Microsoft MVC 3 and do not have an Data annotations on my model.

I have also disabled Client validation on my form by setting Html.EnableClientValidation(false);

My List is: 
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.EventStatusFilter, Model.eventStatus, "--Status Filter--")%>

I don't understand why MVC is requiring validation in this instance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug as far as I can decern.

I found a reference to some codeplex workitems for MVC here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1649193.aspx/1?MVC+3+dropdownlist+validation+not+working+for+complex+view+model

Have a look at the following workitem for MVC4:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7629

There are related workitems for MVC3:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/4932